# How can I do ng-bind-html to be optional in ui-view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's how it works for me for all my states :

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

But I have :

```
<ui-view ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></ui-view>
```

And my problem is :

that `ng-bind-html` in `ui-view` is forcing the `ui-view` to  work only if the expression in `ng-bind-html` exist

And I want to use with `ui-view` for all my states

like if it was like so:

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

so, how can I force the `ng-bind-html` to be optional ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did at the end is like this:

```
<ui-view>
 <span ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></span>
</ui-view>
```

It works for me great !

I do not know how I did not think about it before ..

Answer (score 2):

Using the 2 directives together doesn't really make sense

What you most likely are looking for is to use `ng-bind-html` within template(s) for various routes

```
.state('home',{
     url:'...',
     template:'<div ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></div>',
     controller:'...'
     .....
```

Then leave `<ui-view>` alone to do what it is supposed to do ... be a container for view templates

Comment: A truly beautiful Answer
But in my case there is no template for this specific state, It's just pure HTML content

Comment: Then I suggest you outline your configuration in more detail. The first part of my answer still holds... it doesn't make sense using the 2 directives together

Comment: why ? ui-view is in the index and I use with property views with the @ symbol to bindiing the content of each state to ui-view in the index. If I understood correctly what you said..

Comment: Look... both directives are intended to populate the innerHtml so you need another element for `ng-bind-html` otherwise they conflict in intent. I really don't see why you are resistant to using my suggested approach since there is no `ng-bind-html-optional`

Comment: The controller for each state is called twice
If I create two elements
<ui-view> </ ui-view>
and
<ui-view ng-bind-html = "htmlContent"> </ ui-view>

Comment: I think to use your idea
every time the html created
it's a good idea.